# Plots with partly frayed, blurry letters

Tags: plot, octave

I try to upgrade from Octave 6 to Octave 8 on Windows, but the text in plotted images is often frayed/ blurry. It does happen with all letters, but more often at lower font sizes. I tried a lot of combinations but did not found a cause. It seems to happen quite often but not always.

I tried `imwrite`, `print` and `saveas`, and file formats like JPEG, PNG and BMP, and several image viewers and browsers. Here is an image with marked letters:

[image]

And here is the script:

```
graphics_toolkit("qt");

figure_handle = figure;
figure_handle, 'Position', [0 0 800 600];

imagesc([1 2; 4 1]);

title('aaa vvvv bbbb gggg gggg gggg  QQQQQQ  ZZZZ VVVVV', 'FontWeight', 'Normal');

xlabel('vv lll VVV JJJJ µm'); ylabel('vv lll VVV JJJJ µm');

%set(gca,'FontSize', 22);
%set(0, 'defaultaxesfontname', 'Arial');
%set(0, 'defaulttextfontname', 'Arial');

frame_handle = getframe(gcf);
imwrite(frame_handle.cdata, 'test_umlaute13_imwrite.bmp');

%set(gca,'FontSize', 18);
%set(0, 'defaultaxesfontname', 'Arial');
%set(0, 'defaulttextfontname', 'Arial');
print("test_umlaute13_print.bmp", "-S800,600");
```

Update:
I also tried 7.3.0 on Windows and it also happes there: Sometimes the BMP plot looks fine but the PNG not. Very strange for loseless file formats.

Comment: That looks pretty bad. Did you try a different graphics backend?

Comment: I had to LOL: "Be advised that GNU Octave is primarily developed on GNU/Linux and other POSIX conform systems. The ports of GNU Octave to Microsoft Windows use different approaches to get most of the original Octave and adapt it to Microsoft Windows idiosyncrasies [...]. Bear this in mind and don't panic if you get unexpected results. There are a lot of suggestions on the mailing lists for tuning your Octave installation." https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Qt as backend is the default for some years now. If I choose gnuplot I get warnings because of the old backend. So I guess, that Qt is the best backend.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with Octave 7.1 on Windows 10. I have not upgraded to Octave 8 yet.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Octave 7.3 on Windows 10. BMP and PNG look fine. Does it work any different when you explicitly set the font? Especially in the print statement where you can do `print("test_umlaute13_print.bmp", "-S800,600", 'FontFamily', 'Arial');`